# Iphone app facebook connection?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

hello i have a app that connects and post to user wall but when i try to post it always open the persmission page and in that page it writes you already give permission to this app.I want it to come only 1 time can anyone help me to do that?

```
- (id)init {
if (self == [super init]) {
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId];
    facebook.sessionDelegate = self;
    if(permissions==nil){
    permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    @"read_stream", @"user_birthday", 
                      @"publish_stream", nil] retain];
    }
    [self login];
}
return self;

}

- (void)login {
if (![_session isConnected]) {
    [self postToWall];  
}

// only authorize if the access token isn't valid
// if it *is* valid, no need to authenticate. just move on
if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
}
```

is it because i init method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this page - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/. Basically what you want to do is save the authentication information (access_token) when the user is authorized, then next time you can check for the saved values and skip the authentication.